# Aplicação do Phonegap não instala no dispositivo

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Trabalhar com Phonegap/cordova e encontrar documentação para ele em português é bem complicado, então fazer perguntas sobre problemas enfrentados ajudará a enriquecer com os conteúdos.

Meu problema está sendo ao executar no CLI o comando `phonegap run android --device`, o dispositivo está conectado no computador, mas o Phonegap exibe erro, ao não encontrar o dispositivo ele muda para o emulador e tem instalar no emulador, quando executado o comando sem o parâmetro `--device`.

[Encontrei no Stack em inglês uma sugestão que foi aplicada sem sucesso.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767810/running-phonegap-on-device-no-device-found)

Se alguém já passou por isso e tem outra solução eu agradeço.
Algumas configurações dos dispositivos e versões para facilitar na resolução do problema.

- Smartphone Samsung GT-S5312B Android 4.1.2
- Kies 2.6.2.14014_5
- Versão do Phonegap 3.3.0-0.19.4
- Versão do Cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2

Comment: Instalou o Kies? No meu PC os dispositivos da samsung só são reconhecidos depois que instalo o Kies. Verifique a versão do Kies também.

Comment: Sim está instalado. Estou instalando um atualização, espero que corrija o erro.

Comment: Confere a versão o Kies, como te disse. Pois uma das versões (o Kies 3) só reconhece dispositivo mais novos (Galaxy S4 para cima).

Comment: O Kies está atualizado, continua sem funcionar.

Comment: @LucasNunes Descobri o problema e responderei a minha própria pergunta já que se trata de um erro bem atípico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro citado acima ocorre quando não é encontrado as Apks para o projeto Android. Em alguns casos após um clean and build usando o Eclipse, deleta alguns arquivos importantes do Cordova(aka Phonegap).

Como solucionar utilizando Phonegap(para Phonegap substituir `cordova` por `phonegap`):

1º Se não for encontrado as apks no caminho `SeuProjeto/platforms/android/bin`, execute n CLI o comando `cordova build android`, caso não seja gerado as apks use o comando `cordova update android`

2º Faça o build da sua aplicação para testar, nesse ponto o build já acontecerá sem erros.